# Keeping track of on/offs without index-only tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm looking for the best, most scaleable way of keeping track of a large number of on/offs. The on/offs apply to items, numbering from 1 to about 60 million. (In my case the on/off is whether a member's book has been indexed or not, a separate process.)

The on/offs must be searched rapidly by item number. They change constantly, so re-indexing costs can't be high. New items are added to the end of the table less often.

The idea solution would, I think, be an index-only table--a table where every field was part of the primary key. I gather ORACLE has this, but no engine for MySQL has it.

If I use MySQL I think my choice is between:

1. a two-field table--the item and the "on/off" field. Changes would be handled with UPDATE.
2. a one-field table--the item. Being in the table means being "on." Changes are handled with INSERT and DELETE.

I am open to other technologies. Storing the whole thing bitwise in a file?

Comment: Discussion on LibraryThing: http://www.librarything.com/topic/115692

Comment: MySQL supports index-only tables just fine.
create table indexed_books(id int primary key) engine=innodb;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have more flexibility by using option #1, but both would work effectively.  However, if speed is an issue, you might want to consider creating a HEAP table that is pre-populated on mysql startup and maintained in-situ with your other processes.  Also, use int, and enum field types in the table.  Since it'll all be held in memory, it should be lightning fast, and because there is not a lot of data stored in the table, 60 million records shouldn't be a huge burden, memory-wise. If I had to roughly estimate:

int(8) (for growth, assuming you'll exceed 100million records someday)

enum(0,1)

So let's round up to 10 bytes per record:

10 * 60,000,000 = 600,000,000

That's about 572 MB worth of data, plus the index and additional overhead, so let's roughly say.. a 600 MB table.  If you have that kind of memory to spare on your server, then a HEAP table might be the way to go.

Comment: Hey John! Right. I was thinking I might have the reading part work through memcached. The items always belong to the same users, so most of the time storing all a users books' on/off status in a single memcached key would work. But the data needs to go somewhere permanent. Currently the UPDATE commands are killing the servers. I think this is because the field is just one among many in a large row structure.

Comment: Are you talking about when the user toggles their book on/off?

Answer (score 1):

60 million rows with an ID and an on/off bit should be no problem at all for MySQL if you are using InnoDB.

I have an InnoDB table that tracks which forum topics users have read and which post they've read up to. It contains 250 million rows, is 14 bytes wide, and it is updated constantly... It's doing 50 updates a second right now and it is midnight so peak time could be 100-200?.

The indexed columns themselves are not updated after insert. The primary key is (user_id, topic_id) and I add new last_read information by using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

I measure constantly and I don't see any contention or performance problems but I do cache reads a lot in memcached since deciding when to expire the cache is very straightforward.  I've been considering sharding this table by user in order to keep growth in check but I may not even bother storing it in MySQL forever.

> I am open to other technologies. Storing the whole thing bitwise in a file?

Redis would be a great alternative. In particular, its [sets](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) and [sorted sets](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) would work for this (sorted sets might be nice if you need to grab a range of values using something other than the item ID - like last update time)

Redis might be worth checking out if you haven't already - it can be a great addition to an application that relies on MySQL and you'll likely find other good uses for it that simplify your life.